# How to link an old version of node in mac using homebrew

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am trying to link to an older version of node using homebrew in my mac (because netlify doesn't work with v17 - which is my default).

When I search which versions of node I have installed, I can see that both 16 and 14 are available.

> brew search node
> ==> Formulae libbitcoin-node      node ✔               node-sass            node@12              node@16              nodebrew             nodenv
> llnode               node-build           node@10              node@14
> node_exporter        nodeenv              ode

I expect to be able to run brew unlink node (which works fine) and then

brew link node@16 or brew link node@14, but in both cases, I get an error that says:

> Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node@16

How can I ask homebrew to use an old version of node?

Comment: do you not want to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#about)?

Comment: I'm using homebrew

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```bash
brew link --overwrite node@16
```

Comment: This worked for me for Node v18. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

- `brew install node@16`
- `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin:$PATH"` (you need to put into `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile` to persist the change)

And then I can see the node points to node@@16

```
$ which node
/opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin/node

$ node --version
v16.14.2
```

Comment: on macOS Catalina the  path is /usr/local/opt/node@16/bin